# upgrade back to ubuntu from pop 20.04 lts

Tags: 20.04

Upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 lts to pop and now it hangs a lot. Is there a way to return back to pure Ubuntu 20.04 not pop.

Comment: There is no way to upgrade from Ubuntu to POP. If you have POP, it is off-topic.

Comment: Confirm you upgraded to POP OS or did you install pop os desktop.  Two different things with the first not able to be done without an POP OS ISO

Comment: You'll have to remove all Pop packages; however whilst the upgrade to Pop is easy because *downstream* use higher package versions, which package tools always update to (ie. higher package versions should mean later software, it doesn't in this case though), those tools won't go backwards easily as they're not intended to. The easiest method is to restore backups, or re-install. Otherwise it's a rather manual tool as *automatic* tools are designed to only use *later* versions of packages.  Be careful when adding sources intended for other distributions...

Comment: I definitely upgraded to pop but a month back. the process i followed was adding all the pop repositories and doing a full system upgrade. It's not off topic because a lot of users are facing similar issues after upgrading to pop from ubuntu. Please there must be aa way to UPGRADE to ubuntu no matter what distro it is.

Comment: There is no way to "upgrade" from one distro to another. You can do wrong thing that looks like "upgrading".

Comment: You are **not** running Ubuntu, as you replaced the Ubuntu repository software with the Pop software.  As stated the package tools upgrade to later software automatically, but cannot go backwards as they were designed to prevent this. Pop and downstream distros like Mint use this (and other things) so they can use Ubuntu packages (yet replace them when they wish), but it's one-way. To reverse requires restoration of a backup you created before you did it (if you backed up), or re-install.  The other alternative is to *upgrade* to a later release eg. Ubuntu 20.10 when released

Comment: @NikhilSethi You can try reverting back packages using `ppa-purge` but that won't guarantee getting back clean Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

even though Pop_os is based on Ubuntu, you need to know that Ubuntu 20.04 and Pop_os are two different linux distributions and therefore work in slightly different ways.

Btw, to go back to Ubuntu 20.04 lts, you just have to create a usb support with the os iso (in your case you can download it from here https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.1&architecture=amd64) and reinstall the operating system.

Comment: Is there an easier way so that I can keep my distro settings intact.

Comment: Ubuntu (desktop) can be re-install without overwriting user files using *something-else* install without format of partition(s) (key is not to format your /home partition). It'll erase system directories, so some server applications, plus any configs stored in system directories will be lost, but desktop & user files are stored in /home which isn't touched unless you format.